# How to handle axios HTML response in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I'm sending a POST request to an API using Axios which gives me a response in HTML. I'm rendering that response on a Model WebView which I've already implemented.

```
axios.post(url, data).then((response) => {
   setReqHTMLResponse(response)
})
```

And then the above code snippet change this state below:

```
const [reqHTMLResponse, setReqHTMLResponse] = useState(null);
```

And finally, I'm using a WebView to display the HTML response:

```
<WebView
  style={{ flex: 1 }}
  source={{ html: `${reqHTMLResponse}` }}
/>
```

I get `[object Object]` printed on the WebView. I've tried `${reqHTMLResponse}` without `${}` and doing so throws multiple warning and errors and they are:

> Exception thrown while executing UI block: 'parentNode' is a required parameter

and another one

> Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

another one is

> [3165, "RNCWebView",{"source":{"html":{"data":"\r\n\r\n<!--Commented line, this file...

and the last one is

> Can't perform a React state update on an. unmounted component. This is a no-op...

The HTML response is correct I've verified it in postman it's all clean. So, **what I'm doing wrong in order to display it on the WebView?**

**!!! UPDATE: !!!**

The response I'm getting I did `console.log` and copied the entire thing in JSON Formatter and although it gave me an error that the JSON format is Invalid but I was able to see that HTML is a string that is under the `data` key:

[image]

The red `"` indicates that the JSON format is wong by the JSON format website.

If I try to pass it as `res(response['data'])` or `res(response.data)` I get a blank. page with warning stating:

> Error opening URL: Error: Unable to open URL: file:///HOME_DIR_PATH/CoreSimulator/Devices/....NoURLError.asp

**!!! UPDATE 2 !!!**

If I do `source={{ html:` ${JSON.stringify(iPay88HTMLResponse)} `}}` I get this string HTML on the WebView

[image]

Comment: Try `${JSON.stringify(reqHTMLResponse)}`. Or if that doesn't work, `JSON.parse`.

Comment: @kilinkis doing this prints `{"data":"\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n....` Seems like it converts the HTML response into JSON sting and just printing everything as a long string. I see some HTML text fields rendered as well but the values in those fields are not making sense like in one text field there is a value `\"\"`

Comment: @kilinkis I've updated the question based on your comment, kindly refer to UPDATE 2.

Comment: hmm I see. Are you sure the response is correct? I mean since you get that red quote

Comment: @kilinkis if I send the request using postman then yes the response is correct as I see HTML as response type and it displays the HTML code only no `data` or anything else, but if I `console.log` it and then paste it in JSON beautifier then no it gives red quote `"data":"ALL_HTML_CONTENT_IS_HERE"`

Comment: what do you have in `url`? try giving it the full URL, with `https://`. See more here https://css-tricks.com/stay-dry-using-axios-for-api-requests/

Comment: Yes, I'm providing the full URL with `https://` actually I'm implementing a service for payment and I send the request and I'm supposed to get HTML in response or even if JSON I need which I'm getting but the `"data": "...` is wrong for some reason. The only thing I'm not able to figure out is that. the call works fine on postman but it's not. working using Axios.

Comment: it seems like here you should be passing `.data`, like so: `source={{ html: ${JSON.stringify(iPay88HTMLResponse.data)} }}`

Comment: I tried adding `.data` before as in now it's `source={{ html: `${JSON.stringify(iPay88HTMLResponse.data)}` }}` but then it gives an error `null is not an object (evaluating 'iPay88HTMLResponse.data')`

Comment: maybe `iPay88HTMLResponse?.data`. That works at least on es6, not sure if available in RN

Comment: @kilinkis nope doesn't work... `Error opening URL: Error: Unable to open URL: file:///HOME_DIR_PATH/CoreSimulator/Devices/....NoURLError.asp`

Answer (score 0):

axios response returns an object of all http request stuff. Set to the state response.data , or see what contains in response object with console.log.

Comment: I've updated the question based on your suggestion. Kindly check now.

Comment: Also based on the response I get in postman it automatically shows the response in HTML and not the `data` or anything that signals that the response might be JSON.

Comment: Have the same error when printing the log fails ... it seem the content was too much to handle or to printed