# log axios response.data is causing react native app to crash

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, axios, fetch-api

Everything works fine if using a URL that returns JSON e.g https://learn-numbers.herokuapp.com/v2/words/6788/English.
but I am trying to load HTML content from any URL
I would had say it was impossible but  Axios-hook works fine only that I don't want to make use of it because it crashes the app when requesting redirecting links instead of the error. Instead of error to be caught with status.

**Now, are there requesting an Api alternative?** that can solve the issue

**what is wrong with the code?**

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';  

export default () => {
  const [responce, setResponce] = useState({ status: 'Initiated' });

   

  const setLink = async ({ link, search, config }) => {
    setResponce({ status: 'Laoding' });

try {
  const newConfig = config
    ? {
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': '0.21.1',
          Accept: '*/*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        },
        config,
      }
    : {
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': '0.21.1',
          Accept: '*/*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        },
      };

  const res = await axios.get(link, config);
  // console.log('received response:Offline process ');
  if (res) console.log(res.data);
  else console.log('res null');
  setResponce({ status: 'Laoded' , res});
          
} catch (err) {
  console.log('received error: ', err.toJSON());
  setResponce({ status: 'error Net' });
}


};

  return [responce, setLink];
};
```

After I import the work and use another js file `import useUpdateLookup from "./hooks/useLookup"`

```
const [responce,setLink]  = useLookup()
```

and  returns this

```
<View style={styles.container}>  
     <Button onPress={()=> setLink({link:"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66830446/how-to-handle-axios-html-response-in-react-native", search:searchOption, config:null})}      
          title="Test URI C" /> 
        <Text style={styles.paragraph}>{JSON.stringify(responce, null, 2)}</Text> 
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating your state like this

```
const [responce, setResponce] = useState({ status: 'Initiated'})
```

And later on in the setlink function setting the state in this manner

setResponce({ status: 'Laoded' , res})

if you want to set the response you are getting from the request in the same state you should add it to the state declaration too .....something like this

```
 const [responce, setResponce] = useState({ status: 'Initiated', data:{} });
```

i wouldn't really advise that tho would be better to create a separate state  variable for it ...eg

```
 const [data, `setData`] = useState({});
```

one other thing to note ..in the axios response the returned data is almost always stored in res.data....'

so setting the state after the request succeeds should look like this

```
setData(res.data)
```

Comment: Removing ```if (res) console.log(res.data);
  else console.log('res null');```   adding ```setResponce({ status: 'Laoded' ,  data:res.data});```  **solved the problem**                 Env using https://snack.expo.dev/ and their online emulator.